# Event OnError is not executed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I am making a package that executes all my packages with "Execute Package Task", I need to configure alerts when a package fails, I try to put a send mail on the event OnError of each "Execute Package Task" I am sure the Send Mail Task is ok becouse I have been executing it and it works perfectly, I put a "Execute SQL Task" in a package executed by my "Execute Package Task" The "Execute SQL Task" have wrong Transact code so the package fails, but when it fails the event OnError from the "Execute Package Task" is not executed, so the mail is not sended; I put other send mail task on the event OnError of the "Execute SQL Task"  and it works perfectly, but by this way I have to put thw Send mail task on every task of each package.

Also I tried put the send mail task on the event OnTaskFailed of the "Execute Package Task"
I hope you could help me, ty, sorry my english is too bad.

Comment: It sounds like you're configuring the OnError handler of each Execute Package Task.  Try configuring the OnError handler at the root of the child package being executed (not the individual Execute SQL Task, but the child package itself)

Comment: Thank you so much thats the answer.

Comment: You're welcome, I've converted my comment to an answer and added a couple of screenshots.  If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're configuring the OnError handler of each Execute Package Task. Try configuring the OnError handler at the root of the child package being executed (not the individual Execute SQL Task, but the child package itself)

Essentially, instead of adding an OnError handler in the master package as below ...

[image]

... instead, add one onto the root of the child package, as below.

[image]